# ContourPlot output dependent on bounds

Tags: plotting

I have a function for an ellipse that depends on time:

```
elip = 1/2 (-((-0.476431 t + x) ((0.551344 (-0.476431 t + x))/t - (0.692939 (0.00786131 t + y))/t)) 
- (0.00786131 t + y) (-((0.692939 (-0.476431 t + x))/t) + (50.1052 (0.00786131 t + y))/t))
```

I want to plot this ellipse at a few different times and so use the following code:

```
ContourPlot[Log[.5] == (elip /. {t -> time}), {y, -150, 100}, {x, 0, 4500}, ContourStyle -> Black]
```

For `time = 1796.66`, `time = 2032.74`, and `time = 2299.85`. For the first and last time this plots fine but for the middle time ContourPlot does not output anything. If I change the bounds of x to be `{x,0,4000}` then the middle time plots fine but the last time does not plot. I have the bounds so large to match the plot area of some other functions and because I would like to keep increasing time without having to dynamically update the plot range as the ellipse grows. Is there some reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: Add `PlotPoints->100`.

Comment: Why? Quote from the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html): "You should realize that since it uses only a finite number of sample points, it is possible for ContourPlot to miss features of your functions. To check your results, you should try increasing the settings for PlotPoints and MaxRecursion." Your ellipse is quite small, it makes sense that `ContourPlot` can have trouble. An alternative would be a `ParametricPlot`, but then you have to construct a parametrization first.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

elip = 1/
      2 (-((-0.476431 t + 
            x) ((0.551344 (-0.476431 t + x))/
             t - (0.692939 (0.00786131 t + y))/t)) - (0.00786131 t + 
          y) (-((0.692939 (-0.476431 t + x))/
             t) + (50.1052 (0.00786131 t + y))/t)) // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;

times = {2299.85, 2032.74, 1796.66};

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[
  (Log[1/2] == (elip /. t -> #)) & /@
   times],
 {y, -150, 100}, {x, 0, 4500},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotLegends ->
  LineLegend[times,
   LegendLabel -> Style["time", 14]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Algebraically, `elip` is easy to analyze and much easier if the coefficients are exact than floating-point numbers (easier for Mma, that is):

```
elipRat = Rationalize[Rationalize@elip, 0];
reg[t_] = ImplicitRegion[Log[1/2] == elipRat, {y, x}];
Show[
 Module[{color = 0},
  HighlightMesh[
     DiscretizeRegion@reg[#],
     {Style[0, None], Style[1, ColorData[97][++color]]}
     ] & /@ Rationalize@{1796.66, 2032.74, 2299.85}
  ],
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> Last@reg[t],
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

Switch `{y, x}` to `{x, y}` if you want the orientation to be in school-traditional order.

If you want to use features of `ContourPlot`, then the following shows where the plot should be focused:

```
N@RegionBounds@reg[#] & /@ Rationalize@{1796.66, 2032.74, 2299.85}
(*
{{{-21.2367, -7.01153}, {788.18,  923.789}},
 {{-23.5454, -8.41455}, {896.339, 1040.58}},
 {{-26.127,  -10.0327}, {1019.01, 1172.43}}}
*)
```

If you want to programmatically determine the range for `ContourPlot` with approximately optimal (minimal) sampling:

```
bnds = N@RegionBounds@reg[#] & /@  (* use reg[t] above *)
   Rationalize@{1796.66, 2032.74, 2299.85};
ctr = Mean@*Flatten /@ Transpose@bnds; (* center of sampling *)
{dy, dx} = (* min. diam. scaled by number < 1/Sqrt[2] *) 
  Min /@ Map[Differences, Transpose@bnds, {2}]/GoldenRatio;
{yrange, xrange} = MinMax /@ Transpose@bnds; (* bounding ranges *)
yrange = {-150, 100}; xrange = {0, 4500}; (* desired ranges if different *)
{ny, nx} = Ceiling[Abs@({yrange, xrange} - ctrs[[All, 2]])/{dy, dx}];

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@ (* makes three equations *)
  Thread[Log[0.5] == (elip /. t -> {1796.66, 2032.74, 2299.85})],
 (* align initial sampling grid on ctr *)
 {y, ctr[[1]] - First@ny*dy, ctr[[1]] + Last@ny*dy},
 {x, ctr[[2]] - First@nx*dx, ctr[[2]] + Last@nx*dx},
 (* adjust PlotPoints to {dy, dx} via {ny, nx} *)
 PlotPoints -> (Max[# + 1, 15] & /@ Total /@ {ny, nx})]
```

[image]

The following shows the initial sample mesh in the area around the ellipses.  The important thing is to get at least one point inside each ellipse. I picked `GoldenRatio` for a safety factor (exceeds `Sqrt[2]`). Dividing by `Sqrt[2]` is on the boundary of optimal ***if*** the axes of the ellipses are parallel to the coordinate axes, which is not quite the case here. I didn't worry about the general case. The requirement is that any `dy` by `dx` rectangle should have at least one vertex in each ellipse. It works here. Clearly, extreme cases such as an ellipse that is nearly an oblique line segment may be extremely hard to deal with using `ContourPlot`.

I bumped up `MaxRecursion` to make the ellipses look pretty. The small ones above are jagged. In this case, the large `MaxRecursion` leads to refinement only in the neighborhood of the ellipses.  It does not lead to the explosion of meshing one often gets and is quite quick in this case.

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[1,  (* initial sample mesh *)
  {y, ctr[[1]] - First@ny*dy, ctr[[1]] + Last@ny*dy}, {x, 
   ctr[[2]] - First@nx*dx, ctr[[2]] + Last@nx*dx},
  PlotPoints -> (Max[# + 1, 15] & /@ Total /@ {ny, nx}),
  ColorFunction -> (LightBlue &),
  Mesh -> All, MaxRecursion -> 0],
 ContourPlot[    (* ellipses from above *)
  Evaluate@
   Thread[Log[0.5] == (elip /. t -> {1796.66, 2032.74, 2299.85})],
  {y, ctr[[1]] - First@ny*dy, ctr[[1]] + Last@ny*dy}, {x, 
   ctr[[2]] - First@nx*dx, ctr[[2]] + Last@nx*dx},
  PlotPoints -> (Max[# + 1, 15] & /@ Total /@ {ny, nx}), 
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Medium, Point@ctr}],
 PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Transpose@bnds
 ]
```

[image]